# Swift: If traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .unspecified, how do I determine if it's in light or dark mode?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-darkmode, mapbox-ios

In the settings of my app, the user can choose between 3 system themes: light, dark, or default (which matches the phone's theme).

I do this by finding the `keyWindow` and setting `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` for dark mode, `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light` for light mode, and `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified` for default.

The problem I'm having is I'm using MapBox within my app and I have both a darkStyleURL and a lightStyleURL. When the user chooses a theme I update the style url as follows:

`self.styleURL = self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? URL(string: darkStyleURL) : URL(string: lightStyleURL)`

But the problem with doing it this way is if the user chooses **default** as the theme, the `traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle` is going to be equal to `.unspecified`. So when the code above triggers, it'll use the lightStyleURL *EVEN IF* the user's device is in dark mode.

So my question is, after setting `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified` is there another way to determine the user's device theme?

Or is there a better way of handling the use case of matching the device theme or switching between all three options? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just follow the device theme?  Is it really worth adding complexity to your app for a feature that users will probably never use?

Comment: UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle

Comment: @Paulw11 that wasn’t really an answer to the question. Thanks and not up to me. Dudnyk I’ll try this out when I get back monday thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle` to get the current device theme independent of the overridden appearance on the window.

Comment: Marking this as "correct" although I am using Eugene Dudnyks answer of `UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle` instead. But it's close enough I believe both work. Thanks for the help!